# Why in QueryOver SingleOrDefault is very slow?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, queryover

I am using Nhibernate in a project, and I am trying to run a simple query to validate user logOn. It is working properly but very slow, and if i remove SingleOrDefault() it gets very very fast.

So my question is: Why .SingleOrDefault makes the following code very slow, and can I replace it by something to make it faster?

```
var user = Session.QueryOver<Customer>()
                    .Where(c => c.Username == username)
                    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Thank you

**Edit:**

This might be a little too much, but I am not quite sure how to filter it. The whole output from nhibernate  during the SingleOrDefault step is :

```
2012-03-07 16:24:09,808 DEBUG NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator - put criteria=Username = Koste alias=this0_
2012-03-07 16:24:09,808 DEBUG NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator - returning alias=this_ for criteria=Username = Koste
2012-03-07 16:24:09,808 DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - Opened new IDbCommand, open IDbCommands: 1
2012-03-07 16:24:09,808 DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - Building an IDbCommand object for the SqlString: SELECT TOP (?) this_.CustomerID as CustomerID16_0_, this_.FirstName as FirstName16_0_, this_.LastName as LastName16_0_, this_.Username as Username16_0_, this_.Password as Password16_0_, this_.PersonalInformation as Personal6_16_0_, this_.LastLogin as LastLogin16_0_, this_.IsApproved as IsApproved16_0_, this_.IsReceiveRightsBulletins as IsReceiv9_16_0_, this_.CompanyID as CompanyID16_0_, this_.CustomerTypeID as Custome11_16_0_ FROM Customers.Customer this_ WHERE this_.Username = ?
2012-03-07 16:24:09,808 DEBUG NHibernate.Engine.QueryParameters - BindParameters(Positional0:NHibernate.Type.StringType) Koste -> [1]
2012-03-07 16:24:09,808 DEBUG NHibernate.Type.StringType - binding 'Koste' to parameter: 1
2012-03-07 16:24:09,808 INFO NHibernate.Loader.Loader - SELECT TOP (@p0) this_.CustomerID as CustomerID16_0_, this_.FirstName as FirstName16_0_, this_.LastName as LastName16_0_, this_.Username as Username16_0_, this_.Password as Password16_0_, this_.PersonalInformation as Personal6_16_0_, this_.LastLogin as LastLogin16_0_, this_.IsApproved as IsApproved16_0_, this_.IsReceiveRightsBulletins as IsReceiv9_16_0_, this_.CompanyID as CompanyID16_0_, this_.CustomerTypeID as Custome11_16_0_ FROM Customers.Customer this_ WHERE this_.Username = @p1
2012-03-07 16:24:09,808 DEBUG NHibernate.SQL - SELECT TOP (@p0) this_.CustomerID as CustomerID16_0_, this_.FirstName as FirstName16_0_, this_.LastName as LastName16_0_, this_.Username as Username16_0_, this_.Password as Password16_0_, this_.PersonalInformation as Personal6_16_0_, this_.LastLogin as LastLogin16_0_, this_.IsApproved as IsApproved16_0_, this_.IsReceiveRightsBulletins as IsReceiv9_16_0_, this_.CompanyID as CompanyID16_0_, this_.CustomerTypeID as Custome11_16_0_ FROM Customers.Customer this_ WHERE this_.Username = @p1;@p0 = 1 [Type: Int32 (0)], @p1 = 'Koste' [Type: String (250)]
2012-03-07 16:24:09,808 DEBUG NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider - Obtaining IDbConnection from Driver
2012-03-07 16:24:09,840 DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - ExecuteReader took 14 ms
2012-03-07 16:24:09,840 DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - Opened IDataReader, open IDataReaders: 1
2012-03-07 16:24:09,840 DEBUG NHibernate.Loader.Loader - processing result set
2012-03-07 16:24:09,840 DEBUG NHibernate.Loader.Loader - result set row: 0
2012-03-07 16:24:09,840 DEBUG NHibernate.Type.Int32Type - returning '1' as column: CustomerID16_0_
2012-03-07 16:24:09,840 DEBUG NHibernate.Loader.Loader - result row: EntityKey[IPRBA.Core.Domain.Model.Customers.Customer#1]
2012-03-07 16:24:09,840 DEBUG NHibernate.Loader.Loader - Initializing object from DataReader: [IPRBA.Core.Domain.Model.Customers.Customer#1]
2012-03-07 16:24:09,840 DEBUG NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister - Hydrating entity: [IPRBA.Core.Domain.Model.Customers.Customer#1]
2012-03-07 16:24:09,840 DEBUG NHibernate.Type.StringType - returning 'Koste' as column: FirstName16_0_
2012-03-07 16:24:09,840 DEBUG NHibernate.Type.StringType - returning 'Budinoski' as column: LastName16_0_
2012-03-07 16:24:09,840 DEBUG NHibernate.Type.StringType - returning 'Koste' as column: Username16_0_
2012-03-07 16:24:09,840 DEBUG NHibernate.Type.StringType - returning 'Koste123' as column: Password16_0_
2012-03-07 16:24:09,840 DEBUG NHibernate.Type.StringType - returning null as column: Personal6_16_0_
2012-03-07 16:24:09,840 DEBUG NHibernate.Type.DateTimeType - returning '1/1/2012 12:00:00 AM' as column: LastLogin16_0_
2012-03-07 16:24:09,840 DEBUG NHibernate.Type.BooleanType - returning 'True' as column: IsApproved16_0_
2012-03-07 16:24:09,840 DEBUG NHibernate.Type.BooleanType - returning 'False' as column: IsReceiv9_16_0_
2012-03-07 16:24:09,840 DEBUG NHibernate.Type.Int32Type - returning null as column: CompanyID16_0_
2012-03-07 16:24:09,840 DEBUG NHibernate.Type.Int32Type - returning '1' as column: Custome11_16_0_
2012-03-07 16:24:09,840 DEBUG NHibernate.Loader.Loader - done processing result set (1 rows)
2012-03-07 16:24:09,840 DEBUG NHibernate.Driver.NHybridDataReader - running NHybridDataReader.Dispose()
2012-03-07 16:24:09,840 DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - Closed IDataReader, open IDataReaders :0
2012-03-07 16:24:09,840 DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - DataReader was closed after 15 ms
2012-03-07 16:24:09,840 DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - Closed IDbCommand, open IDbCommands: 0
2012-03-07 16:24:09,840 DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager - aggressively releasing database connection
2012-03-07 16:24:09,840 DEBUG NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider - Closing connection
2012-03-07 16:24:09,841 DEBUG NHibernate.Loader.Loader - total objects hydrated: 1
2012-03-07 16:24:09,841 DEBUG NHibernate.Engine.TwoPhaseLoad - resolving associations for [IPRBA.Core.Domain.Model.Customers.Customer#1]
2012-03-07 16:24:09,841 DEBUG NHibernate.Engine.Loading.LoadContexts - creating collection wrapper:[IPRBA.Core.Domain.Model.Customers.Customer.CustomerBookRights#1]
2012-03-07 16:24:09,841 DEBUG NHibernate.Engine.Loading.LoadContexts - creating collection wrapper:[IPRBA.Core.Domain.Model.Customers.Customer.CustomerContactInfos#1]
2012-03-07 16:24:09,841 DEBUG NHibernate.Engine.Loading.LoadContexts - creating collection wrapper:[IPRBA.Core.Domain.Model.Customers.Customer.CustomerMembershipTypes#1]
2012-03-07 16:24:09,841 DEBUG NHibernate.Engine.Loading.LoadContexts - creating collection wrapper:[IPRBA.Core.Domain.Model.Customers.Customer.CustomerSubscriptionTypes#1]
2012-03-07 16:24:09,841 DEBUG NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultLoadEventListener - loading entity: [IPRBA.Core.Domain.Model.Customers.CustomerType#1]
2012-03-07 16:24:09,841 DEBUG NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultLoadEventListener - creating new proxy for entity
2012-03-07 16:24:09,841 DEBUG NHibernate.Engine.TwoPhaseLoad - done materializing entity [IPRBA.Core.Domain.Model.Customers.Customer#1]
2012-03-07 16:24:09,841 DEBUG NHibernate.Engine.StatefulPersistenceContext - initializing non-lazy collections
2012-03-07 16:24:09,841 DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager - after autocommit
2012-03-07 16:24:09,841 DEBUG NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl - transaction completion
2012-03-07 16:24:09,841 DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager - aggressively releasing database connection
```

Comment: I would check count of where result, then get users.First(), I have done before, and was happy with result.

Comment: also, could you check http://perezj.blogspot.com/2010/10/linq-lamba-expressions-performance.html please?

Comment: what do you mean by 'very slow', the trace appears to indicate the query took 15ms (DataReader was closed after 15 ms).

Comment: @Phil Thank you for noticing that, after it we found out that the problem was in the logging. After we reset the logging it started running smooth. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @Phil pointed the obvious we found out that the problem was in the logging, unrelated with the information provided.